# react-native-otp-verify is not working when app is on play store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I am using `react-native-otp-verify` for my react native app. It is working absolutely fine when I am developing it. But when uploaded on play store, then there is its now working.

Below is my code for reference::

```
import {startOtpListener, removeListener} from 'react-native-otp-verify';

useEffect(() => {
  startOtpListener((resp: any) => {
    const regex: any = /\b\d{4}\b/g;
    const matches: any = resp.match(regex);
    if (matches !== null && matches.length > 0) {
      const otp: any = matches[0];
      setValue(otp);
      console.log('otp: ', otp);
    }
  }).catch((err: any) => {
    console.log('error: otp auto read: ', err);
  });

  return removeListener();
}, []);
```

Above code is working while developing, so I don't think there is issue in coding. Do we need to add some kind of permission even though package document mentions that no extra permission is required or there is some other issue??

Comment: Hi Pratteek,
Have you found the solution if above issue?
Thanks